# Ensuring transport encryption for Exchange Online

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Is there a way, with Exchange Online (Office 365), to have administrators warned if EO makes an unencrypted (e.g. non-TLS) connection to another mail server?

We have an audit requirement to ensure that sensitive emails only travel over encrypted connections.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, with Exchange Online (Office 365), to have administrators warned if EO makes an unencrypted (e.g. non-TLS) connection to another mail server?

You do realise that such a warning is probably not quite what you need. In stead of *"we have a security incident because we sent sensitive data in clear text"* after the fact,  you probably want the system to respond with *"we refused to send your message because no secure connection could be established to mail.insecure.example.org"* and prevent such a security incident from happening in the first place...

Most modern SMTP servers default to using opportunistic TLS, I think. That is they will negotiate a TLS secured SMTP connection when both mail servers support that, and will fall back to a plain text connection if the remote server is not configured with a TLS certificate. That is also the default behaviour for [TLS in Exchange Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-exchange-online-uses-tls-to-secure-email-connections-in-office-365-4cde0cda-3430-4dc0-b489-f2c0736c929f).

To force TLS and guarantee that no messages will sent in clear text to either specific destinations or in general you will need [configure connectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow) with your custom policy.

Comment: Hi, I realise the limitation of the approach. However, what I need is a backstop. We will configure known connections with enforced TLS but I need to be able to audit everything else. We cannot enforce TLS globally as this would prevent access to many external organisations (most of which don't need to be sent sensitive information). If I had a way to audit connections, I could greatly reduce the issue over time & demonstrate compliance levels.